# "New Page" button disabled during SiteEdit/Experience Manager

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, siteedit

When we try to edit the pages of our SiteEdit/XPM-enabled website in Tridion on the browser the "New Page" option in the ribbon gets disabled.

Is there any way to make the "New Page" in the ribbon toolbar during SiteEdit enabled?

Is this default behaviour?

Or do we need to make any config changes to enable this button during SiteEdit in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

"New Page" is only enabled once you configure "Page Types". Until then, Experience Manager has no idea what you mean with a "new page".

Check the documentation topic for "[Enabling the creation of new pages](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_C87299D47BC94982B238BA547A4B4A76)" and google "Alvin Reyes page types" for good tips and advice.

Comment: Yes, the button is now appearing. But once we create the page after giving the location, it says 'Object reference not set'. Here is the stack trace...                                                at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SiteEdit.Services.GetPublicationTargetMatchInfoFromWebsiteUrl(String publicationTargetId, String url, SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SiteEdit.Services.GetPublicationTargetMatchInfoFromWebsiteUrl(String publicationTargetId, String url)

Comment: It looks like you may be missing steps in your configuration - specifically configuring Session Preview and the Publication Target.

Comment: We have all the site edit functionality(Update Preview and Finish Editing) running with the existing configuration for Session Preview in the publication target. Please let us know what we are missing.

Comment: OK, then it could be something with your Page Template? Can you try previewing the page in the CM? Experience Manager will execute the page in Preview Mode so that it can use Session Preview to give the user a new page they can start working on immediately.

Comment: I can preview the page in CM which has been used as Page Type to create new page via XPM.

Comment: OK, I'd recommend setting up a new question then, others will miss this discussion if it stays buried in the comments.